# Limit network speed on all computers

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create program in C#.NET to limit network speed on all computers..any idea?

Comment: can't you just have a nice router like one of those linksys with Tomato or other linux software on it then play with the options it provide3s without need to write ad hoc sw yourself? That is surely possible with the device: Linksys WRT54GL

Comment: @Davide: Why does that comment look like spam? And why would I buy a router to limit network speed?

Comment: hi sir! just like traffic shaping, I want to create traffic shaping in C#.net any idea about it?

Comment: @Cody there is no spam at all, I am a developer ;-) I simply have such router and I know I can configure it like that and actually with even more granularity, specifying which host goes at which speed, or download/uploads limits different per host. I think is better to rely on a solid product instead of writing an in-house driver for this "speed limitation", of course if the question was just for exercise or homework than it's not suitable.

Comment: @Davide: Fair enough; the way you made the recommendation just struck me as strange. And apparently you were right about traffic shaping being the intent of the asker. I just assumed they literally wanted to slow down the network speed of all their computers. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sheng, if you would like to sniff what is on the network, you may be able to do it with C# and pinvoke, you can have a look here:

http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/pmon/

or at sys internals's TCPView just to get inspired...

Answer (score 1):

Not really possible as that would require you to write a new driver, as the .net framework is too high level to have access to such interfaces.

Comment: hi sir! just like traffic shaping, I want to create traffic shaping in C#.net any idea about it?

Comment: still requires your program to be between network interface and programs, which would require low level programming not doable via c#. There might be libraries that you could interface with though (via pinvoke). In straight C#? not possible.