# Limiting Bandwidth of your PC using c#

Tags: c#

i have check IPv4InterfaceStatistics Class of C# and its seems it display all Information of your Network, from bandwidth download / upload, Packet Sent / Rcvd, and Speed of your LAN,

Upon checking the properties, i have found out that all of the properties are GET only.

Is there a way for us to set / limit the bandwidth of download / upload?

thanks in advance.

PS :  I need to create an application that will limit the bandwidth of a PC. Thanks

Comment: Maybe [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027858/limit-network-speed-on-all-computers)?

In my opinion that is not possible :-$

Comment: If your router provides bandwidth control (most do), use that.

Answer (score 2):

To do that you will need to create a driver, which is [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75886/50079) to do in C# (or any other managed language). So at least part of your application will need to be written in C or C++.

Comment: hi Jon, your telling me it would be impossible to control / limit the current bandwidth of the PC using a c# program. So theres no way for me to manipulate IPv4InterfaceStatistics since its just a information and activity of my NETWORK CARD? thanks jon for the reply

Comment: @jhaypee: Yes, that's what I 'm saying. You can use a C# program as the user interface, but to actually *do* anything you need native code (the C# program would call this code in the driver after receiving input from the user).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [TcpDump](http://www.winpcap.org/windump/)

will solve you're issue ,learn how to use it than maybe you can control it from C# as a process ,if Tcpdump can't do that ,that give a try with Wireshark i think Wireshark can be implemented within C#